# Parallel Example Jenkinsfile Declarative Pipeline Fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using [Jenkinsfile Parallel Example](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) - hangs waiting to schedule task. I'm assuming the example should work. With the example as is the parallel stage was skipped because of the

```groovy
when branch master
```

so i remove it. Unfortunately, that causes the process to hang. I also added node to the agent label ... didn't help

```groovy
agent { node { label "for-branch-a" } }
```

Can some one tell me how to get this working?

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Non-Parallel Stage') {
      steps {
        echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
      }
    }
    stage('Parallel Stage') {
      when {
        branch 'master'
      }
      failFast true
      parallel {
        stage('Branch A') {
          agent {
            label "for-branch-a"
          }
          steps {
            echo "On Branch A"
          }
        }
        stage('Branch B') {
          agent {
            label "for-branch-b"
          }
          steps {
            echo "On Branch B"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hangs on both branch A and B

```
> This stage will be executed first.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Parallel Stage)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [Branch A] { (Branch: Branch A)
[Pipeline] [Branch B] { (Branch: Branch B)
[Pipeline] [Branch A] stage
[Pipeline] [Branch A] { (Branch A)
[Pipeline] [Branch B] stage
[Pipeline] [Branch B] { (Branch B)
[Pipeline] [Branch A] node
[Pipeline] [Branch B] node
[Branch A] Still waiting to schedule task
[Branch A] There are no nodes with the label ‘for-branch-a’
[Branch B] Still waiting to schedule task
[Branch B] There are no nodes with the label ‘for-branch-b’
```

Comment: ```[Branch A] There are no nodes with the label ‘for-branch-a’
[Branch B] There are no nodes with the label ‘for-branch-b’```
this means you do not have slave(s) with those names, are you sure you configured slaves properly ?

Comment: Thanks, you are correct I haven't setup any slave/agents. I was thinking these were just threads on the master. Can you point me to any info on how to set these up for use with pipeline/parallel?

Comment: pointed to documentation in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Branch A] There are no nodes with the label ‘for-branch-a’ 
[Branch B] There are no nodes with the label ‘for-branch-b’`

this means you do not have slave(s) with those names, set them up according to guide of jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) and then all will work

Comment: this looks like what I need, I will have to spend some time to figure it out. I should add I am running Jenkins in a Docker container and will be attempting to make the nodes/agents containers also

Comment: You can , just be aware that they have ability to connect with each other via ssh and most part is done ;) everything else by guide

Comment: Just to followup: I created the  Jenkinsfile using docker agents. I'm still a bit unclear on the use of labels. I will post as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @BigGinDaHouse I was not creating agents. I have updated parallel example to use Docker agents:
Note: this version works only if we remove 'label' attribute from the docker agent definition.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Non-Parallel Stage') {
      steps {
        echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
      }
    }
    stage('Parallel Stage') {
      failFast true
      parallel {
        stage('Branch A') {
            agent { 
              docker{ 
                image 'alpine:latest'  
                label 'for-branch-a'   # remove this
              }
            }
            steps {
              echo "On Branch A"
            }
        }
        stage('Branch B') {
          agent { 
            docker { 
              image 'alpine:latest' 
              label 'for-branch-b'     # remove this
            }
          }
          steps {
            echo "On Branch B"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```